# Sending Email attachments using Java - org.apache.commons.net.smtp.SMTPClient

Tags: java, email, attachment, email-attachments, smtpclient

I need to send an email with attachment using smtpclient as this does not need me to authenticate for whitelisted senders.

I do have snippet to send a plain text email as below, but struggling to send it with an attachments.

```
client.connect("mysmtp.domain.net");
int response = client.getReplyCode();
if (SMTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(response)) {
    client.setSender("fromJohndoe"@mydomain.com");
    client.addRecipient("toJohndoe@mydomain.com");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("Subject: test\r\n\r\n");
    stringBuilder.append("\r\n\r\nTEST msg\r\n");

    //need snippet to send an email attachments

    client.sendShortMessageData(stringBuilder.toString());

    boolean success = client.completePendingCommand();
    if (success) {
        System.out.println("Message sent");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Error communicating with SMTP server");
}
client.disconnect();
```

Comment: Is there an error?  If so, please post it

Comment: not really, im strugging to find a way to send attachment, even the subject is added in stringBuilder.